# AngularJS - problems with ngRequired and conditional undefined

Tags: angularjs, ng-required

I have always used ng-required with conditionals undefined like that:

```
<input type="text" name="var" id="var" ng-model="variable" ng-disabled="variable === undefined" ng-required="variable !== undefined">
```

I've never had any problems with this until now. I tried with different angularJS versions from version 1.4.9 to 1.6.2 and it happens to me the same, it enters a loop in browser because it changes the value of "variable" between the value that I have given it and undefined and it finishes failing the browser. I do not understand, I do not know why it fails now.

This is the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyCZh.png)

Comment: Would you mind to add a demo?

Comment: why there is `!==` in `ng-required` shouldn't it be `!=` ?

Comment: That is true, if I use undefined the field is disabled, I had not noticed that in this case became the undefined variable. Then I will use the condition null.
I need to know from back which fields are enabled and required, and I needed a way to differentiate them and I had thought of the undefined, but I see that it is not viable.

Comment: What is the point of setting the `disabled` attribute whenever the variable `variable` is `undefined`? This would mean that your input field will be disabled as soon as the user empties the input field. When you remove  the `ng-disabled` directive it should work fine.

Comment: Although remove ngDisabled the problem persists, I already tried that

Comment: Then why do you even want to set the `required` attribute depending on the value of your input field? I would rather use another variable to determine whether your input should be required or not or something like a checkbox, to toggle between `required` and `not required`.

Comment: Okay, that field does depend on another, in fact on what is selected in a select. As soon as the form appears the fields have to be disabled and not required and when a select option is selected, certain fields of the form are enabled and required.
What I had thought was that back I would return the fields that are unlocked and are required in the response when selecting a select option, as these options may change to the client's liking.

Comment: You're right, better to use another variable, which I try is too complicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the same scope variable to determine ng-required (which again targets itself) is not a good idea. So instead use different scope variable to conditionally mark input required or disabled like:

```
<input type="text" name="var" id="var" ng-model="variable" ng-disabled="otherVariable === undefined" ng-required="otherVariable !== undefined">
```

To clearly explain why your code causes indefinite digest loop takes some digging into angularjs framework code, which is waste of time

Comment: Yes, if you use another variable there is no problem, but why does that happen using the same variable and undefined? If I use any other  comparison it does not loop.